# library compiled with C# for anyCPU does not work in 64 bit version of windows

Tags: c#, windows, winapi, dll, 32bit-64bit

I created a Library with C# over a year ago under windows 7 32-bit and it works correctly, this library use the "User32.dll" and "Gdi32.dll" libraries.

at first I compiled this library for AnyCPU it work on 32bit but it does not work on win 64bit, I Also compiled it for 64bit CPUs but the same happened again.

my library uses the "RawInput devices" from "User32.dll" and "GetDeviceCaps" from "gdi32.dll".

Comment: The Platform target setting on a library project is pretty irrelevant.  It is the EXE project that determines the bitness of the process.  Not using proper error checking and fumbling a pinvoke declaration using *int* where IntPtr is required are standard bugs.  Works in a 32-bit process, fail whale in 64-bit.  Nobody can see yours, nor guess what "doesn't work" might mean.

Comment: The solution to your problem lies in the code which only you can see.

Answer (score 1):

[This article](http://channel9.msdn.com/Forums/TechOff/502739-Any-CPU-Is-it-evil) in channel9 says:

> Third party DLL's, which are 32 bit in nature, cannot be accessed from 64 bit clients.  I have yet to see any workarounds for this that actually work.  Apparently .NET DLL's will auto-adjust if compiled with "Any CPU" and called from a 32 bit or 64 bit host client.

And also in [this question](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/644c2f9c-f06a-496a-b497-6420a7919fdb/64-bit-app-calling-32-bit-dll?forum=csharpgeneral) in MSDN:

> A 64bit executable cannot call a 32bit dll and viceversa. Unless you actually need your application to be 64bit, the simplest option is to set it to target x86. This will still allow it to run on both 32 and 64bit versions of Windows.
>
> If for some reason this is inapplicable, a possible solution would be to create a separate 32bit process that would load the 32bit dll, and have your 64bit application communicate with the other process, possibly using IPC (in some trivial case, redirecting the standard input and output can also work, or even just inspecting the return value of the process). In any case, this results in some extra work; I would advise you to review accurately your requirements first.

Comment: thank you Krumia for your Useful reply. I will try it and come back soon with the result.

Comment: This is true, but likely irrelevant. The DLLs discussed in the question exist in both 32 and 64 bit versions.

Comment: thank you David Heffernan for your reply, do you have any suggestion for me? as I said before I use the raw input devices, and the application runs in 64 bit mode without any error, but it does not work. my program uses the raw input to capture mouse but the events it returns are not correct events, I mean when mouse moves I get the  mouse move event but mouse position is a constant at every time, unless any of mouse buttons clicks and then mouse points will move to right.